# Recaptcha actions aren't being logged in the reports

Tags: javascript, recaptcha-v3

I'm executing the recaptcha script like this

```
let data = {
    action: 'homepage'
};

grecaptcha.ready(() => {
    grecaptcha.execute('RECAPTCHASITEKEY', data).then((token) => {
        recaptcha_token = token;
    });
});
```

And it works 'fine', except that the action is always being logged as submit in the reports. Does anyone know if there's anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we've gone live, we're now getting the action logged in the google console, so I guess it needed a large dataset before it started logging